# Any JavaScript obfuscators that don't use eval in the produced obfuscated code?

Tags: javascript, eval, deobfuscation

I am looking for a JavaScript obfuscator tool that doesn't use eval in resulted obfuscated code.

All the tools I've seen so far use eval in resulted code.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this ?

Comment: i want to use code in adobe air. and it dont allow you to use eval

Comment: How about replacing `eval(...)` with `Function(...)()`? They are slightly different in behavior, but that might not matter here.

Comment: @kangax i had thought of this already .But i doubt this solution as this way the scope of variable will not be global

Comment: well, `eval` doesn't evaluate code in global scope either, but in the scope of a caller (unless it's an indirect eval call or eval is called from within global scope). You can use `Function()()` and create global variables in such way so that it would work when evaluated from any scope, e.g.: instead of `Function('var myGlobalVar = ...')()` use `Function('this.myGlobalVar = ...')()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None. An obfuscator by definition needs to have a way to execute arbitrary code, and in JavaScript, that is accomplished with `eval`.

Comment: cant it be done like write everything in a function and then execute the function ? this way it wont have global scope. May be some tool accomplished this sort of thing.

Comment: I suppose you could `eval` within a self-executing function.

Comment: Where is this is "definition" of an obfuscator?